# How to define a constant/macro in CN1 CSS (theme.css)?

Tags: codenameone

I believe I remember seeing a post from Shannah once describing how to define reusable constants (kind of like macros) in CSS.

So that a value like "3mm" can be defined once and simply referred to by a logical name like "spacing" elsewhere in the theme.css file.

However, I've googled and looked everywhere in the CN1 doc and blogs without finding it, so I was hoping someone could help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example defining and using a CSS variable

```
#Constants {
    --main-bg-color: red;
}

MyContainer {
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

See the section 5.6 "CSS Variables" of the developer guide in PDF, page 164:
https://www.codenameone.com/files/developer-guide.pdf

Oddly, this section of the developer guide is currently missing in the html version of the developer guide, maybe there are not synchronized: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/css.html